# How do I export text to/access text from another file in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, text, react-hooks, export, native

In an AuthProvider.js, I have the following code written to catch and log errors in the console.

```
export const AuthProvider = ({children}) => {
    const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
    const [errorText, setErrorText] = useState('')

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider
            value={{
                user,
                setUser,
                login: async (email, password) => {
                    try {
                        await auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                    } catch(e) {
                        setErrorText(e);
                        console.log(e)
                    }
                },
            }}
        >
            {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

I want to export these errors as text (strings) to another file (LoginScreen.js) so that the error can be displayed there in a Text component, as follows:

```
<Text style={styles.errorMsg}>{errorText}</Text>
```

As you can see, I'm already using a hook to set the error text to the correct value, but I'm not sure how to export this hook into another file, or if there's a better method of exporting a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also pass the `errorText` to the `value` object of the `Auth.Provider`
Since, you'd be wrapping most of your App with `Auth.Provider` you can get access to these values, including `errorText` anywhere in the nested screens.

Inside LoginScreen.js

```
const LoginScreen = () => {

const auth = useContext(AuthContext);
const {errorText} = auth;
    return (
        ...
        <Text style={styles.errorMsg}>{errorText}</Text>
        ...
    )
}
```

Comment: This worked. Thanks so much. Don't know why I didn't think of this sooner.